# c# datagridview not synchronizing

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have two tables to display in my data grid view. my first table should display on first row specifically, and the second table should follow through on the next row. but second table is also taking the first row

```
//from first table   
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=academic;Trusted_Connection=TRUE"))
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from lectureOver", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();
    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Total Attendance";
    dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "attendanceTotal";
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}

//from second table
dt = new DataTable();
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=academic;Trusted_Connection=TRUE"))
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Lecture", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();
    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Total Attendance Raw Score";
    dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "attendanceRawScore";
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Comment: You are setting 'DataSource' over again. I bet the first table is also disappeared after the second table arrives?

Comment: yes, what should i do to combine them in one datagridview?

Comment: Why not retrieve the data from the db with one `UNION` query

Comment: I agree with what @Ivan said. Because you also want to set column names separately. That would be a lot work unless you obtain one table combining two columns using UNION. Search google for"sql union" and you will find plenty of examples

Comment: thank you so much guys for the help.. union solved my problem